# Laravel 5.2 didn't mutate attribute when model "create" method used

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to implement "auto-encryption" for my model's password attribute, using mutator like this:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

This works perfect when I'm creating and saving model like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->login = 'WalterSobchak';
$user->password = 'MarkItZero!';
$user->save();
```

However, when i'm using **create** method:

```
User::create([ 'login' => 'WalterSobchak', 'password' => 'MarkItZero!' ]);
```

mutator didn't have effect and model is creating with plain password field.

I'm definitely missing something obvious, but really can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: That is strange. The create method uses the `fill` method to populate the model and that in turn uses the `setAttribute` method that checks for the existence of a set mutator... I can't see a reason why your example wouldn't use the mutator.

Comment: If I were to guess, Andrii probably overrode the `__construct` or `fill` method and changed the default behavior of the models.

Comment: @ThomasKim OMG! BINGO! I'm using trait with boot method to implement 'created_by' attribute. Well, of course, I forgot to parent::boot. I feel so awkward. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Filling so awkward, but the reason was in my trait with "boot" method in it. After small edit in it model mutators works like a charm.